# Trying to .Include a navigation property when using a return value on a webmethod

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webmethod

So I am trying to have a web method return an object which has a 1 to many relationship in EF. I am expecting the XML to build child nodes for each item in the many relationship, but it appears that the only relationships being populated are the ones going back up, not the ones going down. Here's my code.

```
[WebMethod]
public Question GetCurrentQuestion(int TeamID)
{
    var db = new DSG_pepsicenter_stagingEntities();
    return db.Questions.Include("QuestionAnswers").First(n => n.TeamID == TeamID);
}
```

Basically my Questions table belongs to a team, and has many Question Answers. However, the Question Answers  are not present in the serialization that happens in the web method. Is there a way to force this? I know if I force it I risk an error with circular references but this is preferred to building a DTO. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not terribly clear on what your asking but I think youre wanting to populate the backreference on the other end of a many statement, ie what the question for a specific answer was.

This can be done with the include syntax using the dot notation, ie:

```
.Include("QuestionAnswers.Question")
```

Comment: Even going in this opposite direction, the serializer seems to ignore the 'include' navigation properties when serializing and returning the EF object.